# Add or subtract 212 in octal to get a palindrome

Tags: mathematics, number-theory, palindrome

The puzzle is as follows:

> Suppose you have a three-digit number in the octal system. If you add
> or subtract 212 (also in the octal system) from that initial number,
> you get a three-digit palindromic number in the same system. How many numbers will follow that peculiar rule?

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

1. 14
2. 18
3. 15
4. 21

I'm totally lost on this problem. It seems that the author is trying to say:

$\overline{abc_{(8)}}-212_{(8)}=\overline{ede}_{(8)}$

and

$\overline{abc_{(8)}}+212_{(8)}=\overline{fgf}_{(8)}$

But from these alone, it seems like a ton of options work within the peculiar rule.

Is there a way a way to solve this puzzle without much fuss?

I'm not sure how to solve this but. I would appreciate answers that refrain from using advanced forms of modular arithmetic or whatsoever. I'm looking for a more intuitive or less sophisticated approach, something akin to common sense.

Is this possible? Please **try to do not skip steps and describe as much as possible** because this part I have problems understanding.

For reference this puzzle isn't from a book but from a separate sheet which different puzzles which I had. But from the way how it is presented I think it is an adaptation from Martin Gardner's Puzzle carnival from 1970s.

Comment: Please, stop using MathJax to format numbered lists. Markdown formatting works fine and is more accessible.

Comment: @bobble I sorry about that. I will double check next time. I am so used to work with mathjax tables that I forget that here I better not use them. I hope this is not the reason for the downvote. Again, sorry.

Comment: Judging by the very small number of answers you have accepted so far (only 2, over 30 questions), it seems like you are very unsatisfied with the answers you are offered by us. What are we missing?

Comment: @xhienne Sorry about that. Some answers are good and helped me. I'll update this as I can. Others have left me in doubt, and in some other cases more than one answer was good so I couldn't decide which one to accept. But I want to say that I feel this community has helped me a lot.

Answer (score 5):

There is indeed a simple solution. The key thing to realize is

> You needn't count the described numbers abc themselves, you can count the pairs of palindromes abc-212 and abc+212 instead. (That way you needn't argue about the structure of abc---does it have to be palindromic itself? etc.---at all.)
>  
>  Those can be written xyx and xyx+424. Obviously, for both to be three octits palindromes there can't be carry, therefore 1<=x<=3 and 0<=y<=5. These can be freely combined, therefore the solution is 3x6=18.